# Obtener el atributo href de un enlace y establecerlo como contenido del enlace

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un listado con varios enlaces que contiene solo el atributo `href`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https:///www.google.com"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https:///www.youtube.com"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https:///www.twitter.com"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Debo obtener el atributo href de cada enlace para ponerlo como texto del enlace, pero al imprimirlo en consola me aparece como `undefined`. En el archivo `script.js` tengo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').each((index, value) => {
    var enlace = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(enlace);
    $(this).text(enlace);
  });
});
```

Esperaba este resultado:

[image: resultado]

Pero me sigue apareciendo vacío:

[image: vacio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo modifica el each de jquery, y con eso tienes

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').each(function(){
    var enlace = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).text(enlace);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https:///www.google.com"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https:///www.youtube.com"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https:///www.twitter.com"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando un selector al contenedor de los enlaces, algo como esto.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Obtenemos el listado con los enlaces
    let listado = jQuery( 'ul.listado a' );

    // Recorremos todos los enlaces
    jQuery(listado).each(function(index){

        // Obtenemos en enlace de nuestra etiquetad A
        let enlace = jQuery(this).attr( 'href' );

        // Cambiarmos el .text del item
        jQuery(this).text( enlace );
        
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Listado de Enlaces -->
<ul class="listado">
     <li><a href="https:///www.google.com"></a></li>
     <li><a href="https:///www.youtube.com"></a></li>
     <li><a href="https:///www.twitter.com"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Una vez con el selector obtienes todos los items a dentro de nuestro contenedor, los recorres y luego los actualizas.

En vez de una función de flecha solo ejecutas una función normal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').map(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).attr("href"))
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https:///www.google.com"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https:///www.youtube.com"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https:///www.twitter.com"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Intenta con esto